# Keep only the first word of each line in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

For example I have:

```
hello I am ...
For the reason ...
Not sure if ...
```

I would like to keep the `hello` and `For` and `Not` and get rid of the rest in each line in notepad++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Find:**

```
^([^\s]*)\s.*$
```

**Replace:**

```
\1
```

**Explanation:**

```
^          start of line
([^\s]*)  match and capture every non whitespace character up until
\s         the first whitespace character
.*         consume remainder of line until reaching the
$          end of line
```

Comment: Why make non white space not greedy?

Answer (score 1):

Set the search/replace to regular expression mode, then search for

`^(\w+).*` (capture as many word-characters as possible at the beginning of each line)

and replace ALL with

`$1` (the captured word)

Also, make sure ". matches newline" is off

Comment: The first capture group in Notepad++ is `\1` _not_ `$1` ... `$1` looks like a Java capture group.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: you can use either one in Notepad++. Try it!

Comment: Hi Brian, I had no idea, thanks for correcting me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending of what is a word for you, there're different solutions:

- If a word is only alphabetic character

  - Find what: `^([a-zA-Z]+).*$`
  - replace with: `$1`
- If you want to match letters from any language:

  - Find what: `^(\p{L}+).*$`
  - replace with: `$1`
- If a word is any "word character" ie. `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`:

  - Find what: `^(\w+).*$`
  - replace with: `$1`
- If a word is any non whitespace character:

  - Find what: `^(\S+).*$`
  - replace with: `$1`

Make sure `Regular expression is checked`  but NOT `. matches newline`

Then click <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+H, use Perl Regex, replace

```
^(\w+)\s.*$
```

to

```
$1
```

Comment: It does what I want but only for the first line, everything else gets deleted.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. Just did a test. Please replace  ^(\w+)\s.*$. to $1